how to solve this error
{
"success": false,
"message": "NFT transfer failed.",
"error": "Signature tnpzxNCD48py66wBQuZJbeqNq5uwe7EcoSx8fxZSbBpf2QMu6CD8C3w3XSvaBLoKJXnDUZ3nGPK8eAwT9rtM1Em has expired: block height exceeded."
}

The error means that the blockhash you used to transmit the tx isn't recent enough for processing your tx.
You'll need to try sending the tx again.
Also, a gotcha you might want to verify is that you are on the correct cluster if signing with a web wallet.
